# how to convert HTML to PPT file using api?

Tags: java, jsp, html-parsing, ms-office, openoffice.org

I have to add a capability that is export a jsp (*rendered as html page*) as ppt file. Previously export jsp as excel using poi and as pdf using iText has been done. I have googled a lot about `html/jsp to ppt java api` but felt unlucky.

FYI, I have converted jsp to pdf so if there is any pdf to ppt convertor API in java, that would also be helpful.

Please suggest me any API or share experience about `html/jsp to ppt converter java api`

Answer (score 1):

please use poi-scratchpad for ppt and poi-ooxml for pptx format.
refer to [poi.apache.org/slideshow](http://poi.apache.org/slideshow) for examples

Comment: Thank you @Bhagyesh but I was looking for something like iText, in which I can pass a jsp/html URL to export ppt.